# Подмена ответа со стороны сервера - как обойти?

Tags: php, парсер, curl, теги, file-get-contents

Пытаюсь с помощью file_get_contents  получить изображение с удаленного сервера в переменную, но мне пишет что

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

Хотя перехожу по этой же ссылке в браузере и все отлично отображается.Ссылка имеет вид(как пример)

```
https://cs.sankakucomplex.com/data/e4/15/e415cbc4a0c3b170ebdf21957d072a97.gif?e=1524847443&m=NE5x3_vCJcLkL3LLjsnAlg
```

Если убирать все до расширения, то выкидывает на редирект с плашкой, что такого изображения нет на сервере.Соответственно в браузере если вставлять этот полный url, то открывает все отлично и сразу отдельно изображение на всю страницу.
Сам тег, откуда дергаю ссылку имеет вид:

```
   <img alt="///тут теги\\\" id="image" onclick="Note.toggle();" orig_height="301" orig_width="815" src="//cs.sankakucomplex.com/data/e4/15/e415cbc4a0c3b170ebdf21957d072a97.gif?e=1524847443&amp;m=NE5x3_vCJcLkL3LLjsnAlg" pagespeed_url_hash="3408885876" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" width="815" height="301">
```

В чем может быть проблема?Я так понимаю что это какой-то запрет на скачивание файла с сервера, но как его обойти?

Answer (score 0):

```
Попробуйте так:
$referer = "http://abc.info";
$opts = array(
   'http'=>array(
       'header'=>array("Referer: $referer\r\n")
   )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($node_img, false, $context));
```

Comment: Все равно выбивает ошибку 503.Никак не могу понять с чем это может быть связано.

Comment: Там не конечная ссылка, а идет редирект на файл, по этому и ошибка)

Вот так вы можете получить свой файл:
https://chan.sankakucomplex.com/expired.png?e=1524847443&m=NE5x3_vCJcLkL3LLjsnAlg

Comment: Проблема в том что данная ссылка уже устарела(как я понял там еще и есть определенное время жизни для них), поэтому и выкидывает на плашку что нет такого изображения.Раньше там была обоина в gif расширении.Кстати такая же плашка выскакивала если просто удалить все до расширения скопированной ссылки на изображение. Вот как пример, на данный момент живой ссылки: https://cs.sankakucomplex.com/data/b2/ba/b2ba4a63ad522f69ed8e3db74191f9c2.jpg?e=1525187647&m=_6PE0VdoN7-4wMjt2t4yig

Comment: Если у нее тоже удалить все значения и параметры после .jpg, то вместо обоины выскочит плашка что такого изображения нету на сервере(expired), a если просто ее вставить в браузер, то все норм работает.В то же время через file_get_contents и curl выбивает 503 еррор.Даже забавно как-то :D

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался в чем была проблема.Помимо реферера передавался еще юзер агент и хост, т.к. они оба были обязательными параметрами и отпечатывались еще на стадии захода на саму страницу изображения(Их можно задетектить через GET-запрос в консоли разработчика).В итоге для составления потока массив выглядит следующим образом:

```
$peremx = 'Прямая ссылка на файл';
$opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Referer: Реферер\r\n" .
                  "Host: хост\r\n" .
                  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0\r\n"
                        )
            );
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($peremx, false, $context));
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` передаёт `Host` заголовок

Comment: Ну вот видимо неправильно передавал.Надо было вручную через поток прописать.